# Rails - Migration doesn't throw an error, but also doesn't perform the required migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I wrote a migration where I wanted to delete some database entries that match a required condition.

Here's the code I have in migration file.

```rb
class RemoveRedundantVersions < ActiveRecord::Migration[5..1]
  def up
    delete_version_entries
  end

  def down; end

  def delete_version_entries
     # Checks some conditions and delete objects
  end
end
```

Upon `rails db:migrate` this is the output:

```
== 20190726055203 RemoveRedundantVersions: migrating ==========================
== 20190726055203 RemoveRedundantVersions: migrated (12.2631s) ================
```

Upon `rails db:migrate:status` this is what I see:

```
down     20190726055203  Remove redundant versions
```

For some reason the migration doesn't succeed and falls back to the `down` method. So when I re-run `rails db:migrate` rails would re-try the same migration.

The db table I am dealing with here has a really large number of entries like over 2.5 million of them. Could this be a time-out issue querying them?

I know and am using `for_each` for my db queries so that the migration is run on a small chunk of data at once.

Can anyone think of reasons why this migration fails to do the required job?

Comment: Would a rake task work? If you just need to run this once a rake task would work better than a migration imo.

Comment: I agree, it probably is better! Still, I am just trying to understand reasons why this may have happened!